# How can I quickly load tracers in-between my standard bullets in Escape fom Tarkov?

Tags: escape-from-tarkov

Tracer rounds are an uncommon type of bullets that are outfitted with a pyrotechnic flare chemical. When fired they burn as they travel and leave a brief streak of light which allows the shooter to easily recognize if their shots are on-target. In Escape from Tarkov the munitions work in the same way: when fired the bullet will streak and can be easily used to monitor ballistic effects like bullet drop.

Tracers are typically loaded in two configurations: They're spaced out to be fired every fifth round, or they're loaded as the the last as the last couple of bullets in a magazine. When spaced in the four-to-one format it provides continuous feedback of accuracy without being visually overwhelming. When loaded as the last few bullets in a magazine it informs the shooter that they're nearly out of ammo and need to reload soon.

In Escape from Tarkov how can I outfit my PMC with mags loaded in such a way? I can do it very slowly by unloading a magazine and individually reloading bullets of the tracer and non-tracer type. Is there an easier way to do this? Loading a 60-round with the spaced tracers magazine requires at least twenty mouse clicks, whereas loading it with one type of bullet only requires one click. Is there any way to set a preset magazine so I can capitalize on the benefits tracers provide? Right now, the effort is not worth the tactical gain and I'm better off loading one type of bullet in my magazine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no way to set up presets for a magazine (there have been suggestions for it, but nothing in-game yet).

There is a new capability to right-click a magazine, and select 'load ammo' and pick an ammo type to autoload it now (only with ammo types that fit the mag) instead of drag and drop.

To make it easier if you really wanna customize, you could use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click and drag ammo (this lets you pull a specific number of bullets off the stack). Put them into piles of whatever you want, and then drag and drop those as need be into the magazine.

Most people would just set up the magazine with one ammo type, or toss a couple of a stronger ammo type at the top of the magazine.